# How to configure RAID 5 on HP Proliant ML 350p Gen8 without iLO

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, raid, hp-proliant

one of our customers have HP server with Raid 1 (2 disks) configured. I just added another 4 compatible SAS disks to that server.

I don't have access to iLO (customer lost password and there is no card with default password on the physical server) and I cannot shutdown or restart the server. Is it possible to create Raid on these 4 new disks without accessing the iLO or restarting the server? OS on the server is Windows Server 2008 Standard SP2 32bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lots of options, but the ILO is not critical for this purpose.

For reference, you have use the [HPONCFG utility](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_56d5f9fc7881463da7d801a4c7) from within the OS to configure the ILO, but that's not necessary to accomplish what you're doing.

For the RAID controller, you just have to use the [HP Smart Storage Administrator tool](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_8d0bd720310846469faadb27ca) to configure the new drives. This is a GUI utility, so it should be self-explanatory:

- Create a new *Array* comprised of the four new disks.
- Create a new *Logical Drive* on the new *Array* using the RAID level you desire.
- Go to Computer Management in Windows and format the new device so you can use it.

Comment: I've managed it by myself, but yes, this is the right answer - HP Smart Storage Administrator tool and ACU.